# Combining logical statements onto 1 line in C#?

Tags: c#, coding-style, coding-standards

A simple question as to whether or not this would be a proper way to combine logical statements for readability and organization purposes.

The 'standard' way I was taught to write code:

```
txtbox_vendor.Visible = false;
txtbox_vendor.Enabled = false;
txtbox_vendorCity.Visible = false;
txtbox_vendorCity.Enabled = false;
txtbox_vendorState.Visible = false;
txtbox_vendorState.Enabled = false;
```

Now obviously if I have a huge amount of textboxes or any objects that are being being switched on and off, would it be better to write it like this:

```
txtbox_vendor.Visible = false; txtbox_vendor.Enabled = false;
txtbox_vendorCity.Visible = false; txtbox_vendorCity.Enabled = false;
txtbox_vendorState.Visible = false; txtbox_vendorState.Enabled = false;
```

Obviously, performance isn't going to be an issue.

But is the second option considered a correct way to write code for legibility? Or is it frowned upon?

Comment: Generally speaking I tend to have one semicolon per line (unless it's a `for` loop).  One line, one statement.

Comment: Matthew, this was my thinking as well. It was just a curious thought I had and came across looking at some legacy code.

Comment: Another option to increase legibility may be to create a method that accepts a textbox and sets the `.Visible` and `.Enabled` property in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: I find the second way much harder to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard is one code [statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_(computer_science)) per line.  If a statement is too long, it should be broken across several lines in the file.  The reverse is not true.

Why?

- Automated code merges rely on one statement per line
- Stack traces identify code position by line number; with more than one statement per line, a line number is ambiguous
- One statement per line allows easy reading of nesting via indentation
- One statement per line is consistent with code that is generated by most code wizards (other than minifiers).
- File diff'ing tools such as Beyond Compare are much easier to use with one statement per line

It used to be the following [idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353686/multiple-assignment-in-one-line) was not common but somewhat acceptable:

```
txtbox_vendor.Visible = txtbox_vendor.Enabled = txtbox_vendorCity.Visible = false;
```

Technically this is one statement.  This works because the output of the = (assignment) operator is the value being assigned.  I find it confusing and it is no longer common or [encouraged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/197482/when-are-chained-assignments-i-e-a-b-c-bad-form).

On a side note, if you are coming across a lot of situations where you are even considering using multiple statements per line, as in your example, I have to wonder if your code suffers from other more serious stylistic and structural issues, e.g. a lack of modularity or failure to honor the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

P.S. You do not need to set `Enabled=false` if you are setting `Visible=false`.  If you insist on setting both, consider using an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to combine them into one call, and therefore one line.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation. I wasn't writing the code this way by choice at first, I was simply following the standard a set of legacy code I was working with had. But after reading these answers and doing some investigating, I decided to refactor and change the program structure. SRP really does help and DRY as well.

Answer (score 8):

Groups of things that are the same can be placed in an array/collection and iterated over to avoid large amounts of identical-seeming code.

```
var textboxes = new[] {txtbox_vendor, txtbox_vendorCity, txtbox_vendorState};
foreach (var textbox in textboxes)
{
    textbox.Enabled = false;
    textbox.Visible = false;
}
```

In this way you might avoid the temptation to save space by placing multiple statements on a single line (which is indeed frowned upon.)

Comment: This addresses the OP's example but not his question, which could include lines of code that are not simple assignment or which involve classes that do not share a supertype.

Answer (score 0):

You can still set all properties with only one value and keep the one statement per line rule by doing this:

```
txtbox_vendor.Visible = 
txtbox_vendor.Enabled =
txtbox_vendorCity.Visible = 
txtbox_vendorCity.Enabled =
txtbox_vendorState.Visible = 
txtbox_vendorState.Enabled = false;
```